# Raster transparency

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have a question similar to [Varying transparency of symbols within single layer in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91537). The only difference is that the raster dataset that I am using is gridded and unique values have been assigned to each grid cell. Now, I want to visually compare this raster with another raster.

Is there a way in the recent release of ArcGIS 10.7 to change the transparency of a raster?

When I try changing the transparency of a raster, instead of fading, the raster changes color. The above referenced question was asked six years ago, so maybe there is an updated method to do this which I am not aware of. Basically, I want to make the overlying raster a bit transparent, so that I can visually see the underlying rater, and do a visual comparison between the two.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be, raster or no raster.

Picture shows 50% transparent red polygon on the top of opaque blue polygon:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the raster you want to change the transparency on and click properties. From there if you are not already on the Display tab click on Display. About half way down on the left is Transparency. Enter in any value you would like and lick OK.[image]